# Array de objetos Laravel para trabajar con javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo un modal en vista blade Laravel que se abre cuando quieres borrar un elemento de la tabla (datatables), para advertir si ese usuario es gestor de un local o promotor de un evento, entonces no debe salir el botón borrar. Pero si no es ninguno de esos casos, debe salir el botón borrar y poder eliminarlo. Cuando sale el modal, debe llevar, si es el caso, la lista de locales y eventos que tiene asignado ese usuario. Le paso el array de objetos desde el controlador:

```
 public function index()
{

    /* Conseguir los locales donde el usuario es gestor */
    $places = Place::get();

    $include_places = array();
    foreach ($places as $place ) {

        $user = User::find($place->gestor);

        if ( $user != null ) {

            $to_places = Place::where('gestor', '=', $user->id)->first();
            array_push($include_places, $to_places);
        }
    }
    
    $place_gestors = $include_places;

    return view('admin.users_list', compact('place_gestors'));

}
```

Y en la vista tengo el siguiente script:

```
    //Comprobar si el usuario es gestor de un local
            let place_gestors = {!! json_encode($place_gestors, JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};

            place_gestors.forEach(function(place) {

                $('.btn_delete').hide();

                if ( place.gestor == user_id ) {
                    
                    $('.btn_delete').hide();

                    $('.cancel').removeClass('btn-success');
                    $('.cancel').addClass('btn-danger');
                
                    let text_change = '{!! trans('web.info_change') !!}';
                    $('#info_change').html(text_change);
                    $('#info_place').html(place.name);

                }else{
                    
                    $('.btn_delete').show();
                    $('.cancel').removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('.cancel').addClass('btn-success');
                    
                }
            });
```

El problema es que el nombre del local lo escribe bien, pero solo en el primer elemento de la iteración salen los botones adecuados. También tengo el problema que puede ser gestor de varios locales y solo me aparece uno.
Para eventos sería el mismo caso, pero al poner el script se mezcla con la respuesta de locales y no me da el resultado o los resultados que necesito. Probé poniendo get() en vez de first() en el controlador, pero entonces no funciona en absoluto. No se que mas probar, necesito ayuda, pleaseeee!!!

Comment: y si lo pasas a json de una vez? `$place_gestors = json_encode($place_gestors); return view('admin.users_list', compact('place_gestors'));` o mucho mas fasil solo en la vista `let place_gestors = {{$place_gestors->toJson()}}`

Comment: Gracias por responder, era algo mas complicado que tu solución. Ahí publiqué la respuesta por si a alguien le pueda servir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné!! En el controlador cambié todo, le puse una propiedad nueva a la variable $users para guardar sus locales y sus eventos:

```
    public function index()
{

    $users = User::where('type_user_id', '!=', 4)->where('type_user_id', '!=', 1)->get();

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {

        $to_places = Place::where('gestor', '=', $user->id)->get();
        $user['places'] = $to_places;

        $to_events = EventPlace::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
        $user['events'] = $to_events;
    }

    
    return view('admin.users_list', compact('users'));
}
```

Y en el script cambié y accedí a las nuevas propiedades iterando dentro de users, volviendo a iterar al llegar a places y a events:

```
      //Comprobar si el usuario es gestor de un local o promotor principal de un evento
            let users = {!! json_encode($users, JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};

            users.forEach(function(user) {

                $('.btn_delete').hide();

                if ( user.id == user_id ) {

                    let user_places = user.places;

                    user_places.forEach(function(place) {

                        $('.btn_delete').hide();

                        $('.cancel').removeClass('btn-success');
                        $('.cancel').addClass('btn-danger');

                        let text_change = '{!! trans('web.info_change_place') !!}';
                        $('#info_change_place').html(text_change);
                        let place_list = '<li>'+place.name+'</li>';
                        $('#info_place').append(place_list);
                    });

                    let user_events = user.events;

                    user_events.forEach(function(event) {

                        $('.btn_delete').hide();

                        $('.cancel').removeClass('btn-success');
                        $('.cancel').addClass('btn-danger');

                        let text_change = '{!! trans('web.info_change_event') !!}';
                        $('#info_change_event').html(text_change);
                        let event_list = '<li>'+event.name+'</li>';
                        $('#info_event').append(event_list);
                    });
                    
                }else{
                    $('.btn_delete').show();
                    $('.cancel').removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('.cancel').addClass('btn-success');
                }
```

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta cuando el sistema te deje